# Emphasizing the sum was greater or less than expected value

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

If some points do not add to an expected value, what is a good way to emphasize the sum was greater than or less than the value?

So, instead of simply stating the fact that `The sum was greater than X`, but I could say something like `The sum is in excess of X`. Similarly, I could say `The sum is in short of Y` for the other case.

However, I feel like they are simpler ways to express these two scenarios. It doesn't necessarily need to use correct mathematical or legal terms. I felt that `is short of` probably works for this case, but `in excess of` did not sound like the proper antonym, and it also sounded a bit to verbose. Any suggestions?

Comment: The idiom is _short of `X`_, not _in short of_. You could consider using a vertical metaphor --  _above_ or _below, far above_ or _somewhat below_. If you are simply footnoting a column in a table, there is a standard phrase "Values do not sum to `X`" that can be used. You can add "because of rounding" or something similar to explain, if necessary.

Comment: the sum fell short of.

Comment: Nothing in your Question suggests emphasis.

For emphasis you would need "… far/greatly/significantly/way short of…"

I suggest the Question belongs either in English Language Learners or one of the many specialist maths groups.

Comment: Use an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your desire for an alternative to *greater than*/*less than*, I would go with *The sum **exceeds** X* and *The sum **falls short of** Y*. @Jim noted the latter in his comment on your question.

**Exceeds** and **falls short of** are stronger that *is greater than* and *is less than* (they are stronger verbs), and they are natural antonyms, which might satisfy your desire for same.

Also, **exceeds** is one word, while *is greater than* is three words.

Comment: Thanks, I really like that. But I also want to emphasize how much the value is off from the expected sum. I guess I could say `The sum exceeds X by <some value>` and `The sum falls short of X by <some value>`.

Comment: @CookieMonster I get it, but you didn't say that in your question. You have to solve that problem with *greater than/less than* and any alternative you may choose. What you've suggested is the only way I know to quantify the exceedance or shortfall. It solves the problem and is perfectly correct.